Помогите пожалуйста с задачей
Нам даны 2 таблицы:
Колонки таблицы user_comments:
«id» — идентификатор комментария.
«publication_id» — идентификатор публикации, под которой оставлен комментарий.
«user_id» — идентификатор пользователя, который оставил данный комментарий.
«time_posted» — момент времени, когда пользователь оставил данный комментарий под публикацией.
«reply_to» — идентификатор комментария, на который данный комментарий является ответом. Если комментарий не является ответом ни на какой другой комментарий, то значение в колонке считается пропущенным.
Колонки таблицы users:
«id» — идентификатор пользователя на платформе.
«gender» — пол пользователя.
«birthday» — дата рождения пользователя.
Реализуйте запрос, возвращающий количество уникальных пользователей без комментариев в таблице user_comments, не используя оператор in, но используя левое (или правое) соединение.
Единственную колонку таблицы, которая получится в результате исполнения запроса, назовите users_cnt.
Пробовал такое решение:
with p as(
  select *
  from user_comments uc
    left join users u
    on uc.user_id = u.id
)
select 
  count(distinct(id))
from p

Выдаёт ошибку
column reference "id" is ambiguous
LINE 8:   count(distinct(id))

Что вам непонятно в ошибке, вы её перевели на русский язык? Смотрели ли вы что выдаёт ваш подзапрос в with, если его отдельно вызвать, какие в нём поля получаются? И совсем уж наводящий вопрос: к какой из двух ваших, участвующих в запросе таблиц, относится id в выражении count(distinct(id)) и как это должен понять выполняющий запрос энжин?

я думал что в p я объединил две таблицы и она получилась как одна целая и в ней у двух столбцов id, есть id и user_id

В обеих таблицах есть просто id, оба этих id попали в выборку select * from ... join ..., какой из этих двух id имеется в виду в count(distinct(id))? Вариантов как это победить много. Можно выбирать не все поля через *, а только нужные, например. select конкретный id из конкретной таблицы.

Все, я понял, большое спасибо!

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) AS users_cnt
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_comments uc ON u.id = uc.user_id
WHERE uc.id IS NULL;  -- Фильтруем пользователей без комментариев

Пример как для решения с использованием левого соединения
